# Find matrix $A$ given the matrix $X$ and that $X = AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I have a matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $X=AA^T$.

How can I find $A$?

Comment: It is far from unique.  Which one do you want?

Comment: Okay, the original problem is the following.
I have an $X$ matrix of two Gaussian random variables of mean $0$ and covariance $I_2$, transform it in a Gaussian random vector $Y=AX+b$, and $Y\thicksim N(\begin{bmatrix}5\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix})$. I have to find $A$ and $b$.
Since $E[Y]=AE[X]+b$, then $\begin{bmatrix}5\\1\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}+b$, so $b=\begin{bmatrix}5\\1\end{bmatrix}$, so it's just $A$ what's left, and since the covariance matrix $C_X=I_2$, then $C_Y=AC_XA^T=AA^T$.
Am I wrong in something here?

Comment: @DavidGuevara Thank you David for accepting my answer, I've given here two methods, the first one is more universal, the second one is easy for graphical interpretation in 2d  and very fast as you need to have made only few elementary calculations mostly trigonometric, the easiest solution is when we assume $\alpha$=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try diagonalization of the symmetric matrix $X$.

You have two eigenvalues $2-\sqrt{2},2+\sqrt{2}$ both fortunately $>0$.

In this case  specific orthogonal matrix $P$ exists such that

$X=PDP^T= PD^{1/2}D^{ 1/2}P^T=PD^{1/2}(PD^{1/2})^T=AA^T$.

From this four solutions
$A=PD^{1/2}$.

You can check that also $A=PD^{1/2}R$ where $R$ is any orthogonal matrix is   a solution.

Comment: As matrix $R$ in 2 dimensions can also have form $I$ or $-I$ then four solutions in $A=PD^{1/2}$ will be reduced to two (what is analogue to changing the sign of $\theta$ angle in the second my solution). Arbitrarily chosen matrix $R$ is equivalent to the free choice of the first vector in the second method.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$ and compute $AA^T$ to end up with 4 nonlinear equations in 4 unknowns. Unlikely to have a unique solution but you will have all 4 constraints.

**CORRECTION**

Of course $AA^T$ is symmetric so you only end up with $3$ constraints...

Answer (score 2):

This is typically called the [Choelsky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition): using the notation from wikipedia, your $A = L D^{1/2}$ where $D^{1/2}$ is just that matrix with all elements square-rooted. Unfortunately, your $X$ is the article's $A$ and your $A$ is the article's $L D^{1/2}$.

tl;dr on the article, you can compute this iteratively:

1. Restrict your $A$ to be lower triangular (guarantees uniqueness). This forces $A_{(1,1)}=\sqrt{3}$.
2. Now, $X_{(1,2)}=A_{(1,.)} A^T_{(.,2)}$, and you can go from here (there's one unknown in this second step).

Answer (score 0):

Denote $A$ as a matrix composed from row vectors $r_1^T$  and $r_2^T$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}{r_1^T \\ r_2^T} \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $$ AA^T=\begin{bmatrix} r_1^T \\ r_2^T  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  r_1 & r_2  \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}  \Vert{r_1}\Vert^2 & r_1 \cdot r_2   \\ r_2 \cdot r_1 & \Vert {r_2}\Vert^2\end{bmatrix}$$

From this you can get solutions:

you can take any vectors in $R^2$ with length $\sqrt{3}$ and $1$ and $\cos\angle(r_1, r_2)= \dfrac {r_1 \cdot r_2}{\Vert{r_1}\Vert  \cdot \Vert {r_2}\Vert } =\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Three constraints in this method are two lengths of the vectors and the angle (up to the sign) between them. Advantage of this method is that it can be easily presented graphically..

Comment: So the steps are as follows:   1. take any vector $ r_2= [\cos\alpha \ \ \sin\alpha]$ you can choose any $\alpha$ 2. rotate this vector by $\theta$ angle $=\pm acos (1/\sqrt{3})$, it has components $[\cos(\alpha \pm\theta) \ \ \sin(\alpha \pm\theta)]$ 3. Multiply the result by $\sqrt{3}$ , you obtain $r_1$

Comment: One of the simplest in the form solutions $\{\{\sqrt 3 ,0\},\{1/\sqrt 3 ,\ \ \sqrt 2 /\sqrt 3 \}\} $